# PostgreSQL: A function to add parent & child records

Tags: postgresql, function, parameters, parent-child, custom-type

I am writing a function to add a parent record and children records.

As far as I am aware, I should create appropriate data types, which I have simplified.

```
create type parenttype as (
    data varchar            --  data
);

create type childtype as (
    parent integer,         -- foreign key
    details varchar         --  data
);
```

This is a simplified version, omitting a number fields which add nothing to the question. However, they both also omit the primary key which will be generated.

I think the function would take the following form:

```
function adddata(parentdata parenttype, childdata childtype[])
--  etc
--  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

I *think* I know what to do what to do with the data inside once it gets there.

The question is, how do I set the data before when I call the function? That is, how do I set values for the the `parenttype` and the array of `childtype`?

I have asked asked a related question for MS SQL Server, but I know that this requires a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Depends from what you call that function and where does this data come from.

Example 1

```
SELECT * FROM adddata(
      row('somedata')::parenttype,
      array[row(1::integer,'somedata'), row(2::integer,'somedata22')]::childtype[]
);
```

Example 2

```
SELECT adddata(
         row(parent.column)::parenttype,
         array_agg(row(child.parent_id,child.column)::childtype)
       )
FROM parent
JOIN child ON child.parent_id = parent.id
GROUP BY parent.column;
```

Comment: Could you clarify `array_agg`? Could I add 2 rows that way? Also, in your second example, does it really need the additional clauses after the `SELECT` clause?

Comment: `array_agg` will return array of elements that you pass to it as parameter. In this case it will be array of rows that are childtype type. What do you mean by additional clauses? Second example is building parameters for function from data in tables.